# Can't see new options (like Spaces) on Twitter for Android

Tags: twitter

I have Xiaomi Redmi Note 10S, and MIUI 12.5.4 (Indonesian Rom). I installed the Twitter application, and for some reason, I can't see the new options screen:

[image: screenshot of what new Twitter options screen should look like]

Instead, I see the old tweet screen when I press the tweet button:

[image: screenshot of Twitter missing new options screen]

I already re-install it a couple of times, but no luck.

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you mean there's no "+" icon that shows "Tweet" and other menus like "Spaces", like on Step 3 from [this article on Dev.to](https://dev.to/unclebigbay/guide-to-using-twitter-spaces-19c3)?

Comment: Yes, I updated the Twitter, and still I don't have the new options menu, what can I do?

Comment: [Accounts with protected Tweets are not able to create Spaces](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/spaces). Is that the case with you?

Comment: @beeshyams My account is not protected tweets.

Comment: Maybe try installing from alternative sources that host apps? Assuming you installed this from Play Store

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks I will try to download from their official site and will update here.

Comment: @beeshyams I tried to download from other host (not play store) and still I don't see the new options. Maybe it's related to the fact that I burn Indonesian rom?

Comment: Ohh, ROM issue could be very likely. I don't use Twitter app but downloaded just to check if it is settings related and could see spaces (Pixel 4a running stock Android 11) // I think we've exhausted all possibilities to conclude its most likely ROM retired

Comment: You are in Israel, and running Indonesia ROM. That could be a problem. Try to uninstall and when you install, deny the location access. May help

Comment: I will try and update, thanks.